# htaccess WordPress rewrite rules not working

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I want everything that beginning with
http://www.laurapeckauskiene.com/dt_gallery_category/
to be rewritten to
http://www.laurapeckauskiene.com/
(dt_gallery_category is the archive)

So I have in htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^dt\_gallery\_category.*$ http://www.laurapeckauskiene.com/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

But the requests are still not being redirected as wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
RewriteRule ^dt\_gallery\_category.*$ http://www.laurapeckauskiene.com/
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^$ /dt_gallery_category/ [L]
```

You don't need to include the full URL since they're on the same domain.

Comment: It not working correct. it just deletes "dt_gallery_category". So I get non working link.